# Points for edit taken away or not?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Normally, when a question you edited has been deleted, the two rep from editing is taken back. Today I edited this question: [how to fully implement bfs and make this code better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278076/how-to-fully-implement-bfs-and-make-this-code-better). The question was later deleted, but the two points still show up as part of my rep. However, on http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation, the two points don't show up.

Reputation as seen from my user profile:
[image: reputation from user profile]

Reputation as seen from http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation:
[image: reputation from www.stackoverflow.com/reputation]

So what *is* my reputation: 748, or 746?

Answer (score 9):

Your reputation is 746.

It sometimes takes a little while for the *post deleted* entry to show up in your *reputation* tab. The reputation *audit* (the text result produced by the `/reputation` URL) is always accurate.

Your reputation tab should right itself within 24 hours.

Comment: It is more than 24 hours as of now, and the post deleted entry still has not shown up. I will wait one more day hoping this will correct itself.

Comment: @mmking: I'll poke a developer to apply a manual re-calc. I'm reluctant to undelete then re-delete the post you edited as that'd disallow the OP from ever undeleting it by themselves.

Comment: @mmking I triggered a manual recalc in this case, but normally this isn't anything to worry about - not all events trigger a recalc themselves, but plenty of them do, so this would have sorted itself out no matter what. Thanks for the report, and enjoy ... less rep? :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks. Although that last remark was kind of cruel...